# Can Invoke Duplicity's illusion (the Trickery cleric's Channel Divinity) reach spaces the cleric could not?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, illusion

The [Trickery Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#TrickeryDomain) (PHB p. 62-63) gains the Invoke Duplicity ability as a Channel Divinity option at 2nd level:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to create an illusory duplicate of yourself.
>
> As an action, you create a perfect illusion of yourself that lasts for 1 minute, or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell). The illusion appears in an unoccupied space that you can see within 30 feet of you. As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the illusion up to 30 feet to a space you can see, but it must remain within 120 feet of you.
>
> For the duration, you can cast spells as though you were in the illusion’s space, but you must use your own senses. Additionally, when both you and your illusion are within 5 feet of a creature that can see the illusion, you have advantage on attack rolls against that creature, given how distracting the illusion is to the target.

Can the illusion from Invoke Duplicity do things such as fly up in the air, appear to jump over a 20-foot chasm, or pass through a cage's metal bars, even though the cleric controlling the illusion could not physically do such things?

In short: does the illusion have to obey any laws of physics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, the illusory you has more mobility

Absolutely! The only requirements for Invoke Duplicity are (PHB, 63):

> The illusion appears in an unoccupied space that you can see within 30 feet of you. As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the illusion up to 30 feet to a space you can see, but it must remain within 120 feet of you.

There are no restrictions except for total move of 30' per bonus action and a limit of 120' from you. It is simply an illusion and doesn't obey the laws of physics - just the laws of the Channel Divinity.

Comment: How is Invoke Duplicity a scout? You can't even see or hear through it...

Comment: You can send it out ahead and watch what happens to it.

Comment: @Ruse Mark Wells got it - but i changed my header to be more directly related to OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

## The illusion does not have to obey the laws of physics

Generally, illusions do not have to obey the laws of physics. Looking at other illusion spells, many of them say something like this (this example is taken from *[major image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)*, PHB pg. 258):

> Physical interaction with the image reveals it to be an illusion, because **things can pass through it**.

Since things can pass through most illusions, it's reasonable to assume that there's no reason this illusion couldn't move through bars. Similarly, since an illusion isn't real, there's also no reason why it can't be made to move over a drop or up into the sky (so long as it says within 120' of you at all times); from Invoke Duplicity, PHB pg. 63:

> As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the illusion up to 30 feet to a space you can see, but **it must remain within 120 feet of you**.

Comment: I assume that, based on this line of thought, we shouldn't read "perfect illusion" to imply any measure of realness?

Comment: @YannickMG I read "perfect illusion" to mean "indistinguishable likeness" rather than "believable performance", if performance is the right word to use... you see what I mean, though...

Comment: Why would the text of major image have any bearing on this whatsoever?

Comment: Neither does MI. Each feature/spell etc is completely self contained and independent of others unless they specifically reference it.